# Simulation TSLS in R

Tags: r, simulation

How can I make a simulation study in R for tsls?
This is what I have:

```
K <- 
N <- 
beta <- 1
g <-matrix(ncol=K,nrow=N)

for(i in 1: K)
  g[,i]<-rbinom(N,2,0.3)

u <- rnorm(N)
gamma <- runif(K,0.5,4)
x <-rnorm(N,t(gamma)%*%g+u)
alpha <- runif(K,-0.5,0.5)
y <- rnorm(N, t(alpha)%*%g+beta*x+u)
```

Comment: Can you post more details about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: So I need to make a simulation of two-stage least squares to estimate the causal effect of X on Y. (I need to compare this with beta <- 1) : I have the 3 formula for the confounders (u), exposure (x) and outcome (y). After this I have to compare it with a simulation using Egger's regression